# Cordova File Transfer encodes the encoded URL

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, restangular

I am developing ionic application and using cordova file transfer to download some video files.
Download URL :

```
https://*****/*-52e10254-85c5-459c-98f3-5c5fe89e3326/deb5bcc6-2767-4b45-b57f-94bacd4b_960x540_1500.mp4?sv=2012-02-12&sr=c&si=fb8b356b-b718-490d-8cf5-c4caa1ec03a2&sig=Ioh2qfMVvIAWcYTH2hmE27lP7gzu8%2BasZLdlhS6QwEQ%3D&se=2017-03-05T07%3A06%3A50Z
```

File transfer goes to error block and when I log the error object, the difference I see from the original URL is % is converted to %25.
Ex: %3A is getting converted to %253A

Lib/Frameworks used:
ionic - cordova-Restangular

Comment: Solved : Issue was with cordova download plugin in which it will internally encode and send the URL unless and until explicitly specified.This is solved now.

Answer (score 0):

You get %25 in the place of % due to encoding of the URL. %25 is the encoded value of %

You might solve the issue by decoding the URL before making use of it. Hope it helps. Cheers.